# Is it possible to include JavaScript files as part of my build?

Tags: build, typescript

Is it possible to put a reference in my code to `.js` files and have typescript combine them as part of its final build?

What I'm trying to obviate here is the need for any tools that do combining, script tags, or requiring a loader when all I'm producing are internal modules.

Note: I am not talking about `.d.ts` files which I'm aware of.  I'm looking for ways to include the actual JavaScript files in the `.js` output from `tsc`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried to include `js` file with this, and it worked. The `js` files are added to the build folder.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./build/",
        ...
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Note, in reading this answer I missed the "allowJs" part when looking at the "include" part.